# How to adding large number with stack?

Tags: c#, algorithm, visual-studio-2010, data-structures, stack

```
    class LargeNumberPb
{
    Stack s1;
    Stack s2;
    Stack res;
    string first;
    string second;

    public LargeNumberPb()
    {
         first = "10";
         second = "11";
         s1 = new Stack();
         s2 = new Stack();
         res = new Stack();
    }

    public void Fill()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < first.Length; i++)
        {
            s1.Push(first.Substring(i,1));
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < second.Length; i++)
        {
            s2.Push(second.Substring(i,1));
        }
    }

    public Stack Sum()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < s.Count; i++)
        {
            res.Push(Convert.ToInt32(s1.Pop()) + Convert.ToInt32(s2.Pop()));
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

I want to solve adding large number problem, using stack. but it is not working in a right way, if two numbers are 100 and 11, then where the carry will go?

Comment: 1. If the two numbers are 100 and 11, there won't be any carry. 2. Why are you trying to solve this problem using stacks? 3. Are you aware that .NET already has built-in bignum support? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx

Comment: Is this a class assignment for a calculator exercise?

Comment: suppose two numbers are 8 & 9 then? i want to implement it for figures like 431236748491238564356823.

Comment: Are you doing this for adding binary numbers?

Comment: i think he want to add binary numbers? am i wrong?

Comment: 431236748491238564356823 numbers like this one

Comment: Any chance you get your assignment wrong :) ? - check this one out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923424/how-can-i-add-two-arbitrarily-large-numbers-using-only-stack-allocated-memory-in

Answer (score 1):

If two numbers have equal digit count just fix your sum function (just handle carry, code is not tested):

```
public Stack Sum()
{
    int carry = 0;
    int count = s1.Count;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        var result = Convert.ToInt32(s1.Pop()) + Convert.ToInt32(s2.Pop()) 
                     + carry;
        res.Push(result%10);
        carry = (result - result % 10)/10;
    }

    var carryStream = carry.ToString();
    for(int i=carryStream.Length-1;i>=0;i--)
    {
         res.push(Convert.ToInt32(carryStream.Substring(i,1);
    }
    return res;
}
```

**Edit:** and this is a edited version for different length strings:

```
        public Stack Sum()
        {
            int carry = 0;
            int count = Math.Min(s1.Count, s2.Count);
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                var result = Convert.ToInt32(s1.Pop()) + Convert.ToInt32(s2.Pop())
                             + carry;
                res.Push(result % 10);
                carry = (result - result % 10) / 10;
            }

            var carryStream = carry.ToString();
            var remainedStack = s1.Count > 0 ? s1 : s2;
            carry = 0;
            for (int i = carryStream.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                var result = Convert.ToInt32(carryStream.Substring(i, 1)) 
             + (remainedStack.Count > 0 ? Convert.ToInt32(remainedStack.Pop()) : 0);
                res.Push(result % 10);
                carry = (result - result % 10) / 10;
            }

            if (remainedStack.Count > 0)
            {
                int remainedCount = remainedStack.Count;
                for (int i = 0; i < remainedStack.Count; i++)
                {
                    var result = carry + Convert.ToInt32(remainedStack.Pop());
                    res.Push(result % 10);
                    carry = (result - result % 10) / 10;
                }

            }

            if (carry != 0)
                res.Push(carry);

            return res;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need only one variable for carry on. While you are popping numbers from staks and adding them, if there is a carry on, you assign that value to extra variable you have. That s all you need really.

```
public Stack Sum()
{
    int carry = 0 ;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.Count; i++)
    {
        int sum = Convert.ToInt32(s1.Pop()) + Convert.ToInt32(s2.Pop()) + carry;
        if(sum > 10) { carry = 1} else {carry = 0;} // you might want to check more than 10 here
         res.push(sum);
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: then will i also need to push carry on value to result stack? or i have to do some thing else

Comment: no, you dont need to push the carry on for every addition, you need to add the carry on, to the next addition, and if there is no next addition, you need to push carry on to stack. think about addition. write down two numbers and add them.